# Getting Access to Azure Blob Storage from WinRT app

Tags: azure, windows-8, winrt-xaml, blobstorage

I tried get access to azure blob sotage form my windows 8 app. I see this  [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190), but in him used **Windows Azure Storage Client Library for Windows 8**, i can' find this library on github, google ect. How can i get an access to blob storagw from my windows 8 app&

Comment: Yep - link is broken, I can't find it either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Azure Storage Client Library for Windows 8 is the part of Windows Azure Storage Client library for .Net (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net). Direct link for RT version: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/Lib/RT.

What you would need to do is download the entire source code using the 1st link, open the solution in VS 2012 and build just the `RT` project. You'll then get the necessary `winmd` files.

**UPDATE:**

Actually I downloaded the source code of project from the link you mentioned above and what I found that it does not uses Storage Client Library for Windows 8. It actually uses Windows Azure Mobile Client SDK for Windows 8 which you can download from here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/ (Mobile --> Windows Store). Once you do that, then your code should compile. In order to run the application, you would need to create a mobile service first which you can do by visiting Windows Azure Portal and while you're there, get the application key as well (bottom button bar --> Manage Keys). You would need the mobile service URL and the application key so that you can paste them in app.xaml.cs file.

Comment: If i download azure sdk for .net by this [link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) , or all the same i need to down load from github ?

Comment: The link you mentioned is for the entire SDK and I haven't seen libraries for Windows 8 included there (I download the .Net SDK). You may want to try downloading the SDK for Windows Store (Mobile --> Windows Store) from there (though I'm not sure if that would work). I think the safest bet would be to download from Github (and fastest too).

Comment: Thanks. Windows Store gives references only for an azure mobile services. May be offtopic - in readme on 1st github link writes: "_To get the binaries of this library as distributed by Microsoft, ready for use within your project you can also have them installed by the .NET package manager NuGet._", but when i try to install WindowsAzure.Storage package, nuget give me error "Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.Spatial 5.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain...may be you now how fix it?

Comment: And last stupid question - winmd file i need add in my project by a references?

Comment: Please see my updated response above regarding winmd file. To answer your question about NuGet, this is for your standard .Net apps and not Windows Store apps so going NuGet route will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If any one need older Windows Azure Storage Client Library for Windows 8, then you can download from [here](https://github.com/Xyroid/Microsoft-WindowsAzure-Storage-for-win8). Then also I would suggest to download source and compile it.